# An exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'the0' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to get data from API using Rest Service..
But I got an error saying that the getter was called on null, after doing some research, I found something, like the UI which the data I want to display was executed first than the getData function, it makes the system read the variable as null and the error occurs. Can anybody help me with this case..

Here this is a bit of my codes,

```
class PickUp extends StatefulWidget {
  var created_name, wmsorders_id, id;
  PickUp(
      {Key key,
      @required this.created_name,
      @required this.wmsorders_id,
      @required this.id})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PickUpState createState() => _PickUpState();
}

class _PickUpState extends State<PickUp> {
  DetailModel detailModel;
  String sender = "";

  Future<String> getDetail() async {
    print("id : " + widget.id);
    var data = "id=" + widget.id + "";
    var response_detail = await RestService()
        .restRequestServiceGet(SystemParam.URL_DETAIL_UPCOMING, data);
    print("response_detail : " + response_detail.body.toString());

    setState(() {
      detailModel = DetailModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response_detail.body));

    });

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getDetail();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // NULL CHECKING
    if (detailModel != null) {
          print("sender =" +detailModel.the0.picName);
    } else {
          print("sender = null");
    }

     // I want to get picName from detail Model and using it in UI, but I got Error here

    sender = detailModel.the0.picName'; 
    print("sender = " +'$sender');

}
```

Here is the detailModel

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final detailModel = detailModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

DetailModel detailModelFromJson(String str) => DetailModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String detailModelToJson(DetailModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class DetailModel {
    The0 the0;
    The0 the1;
    Records records;

    DetailModel({
        this.the0,
        this.the1,
        this.records,
    });

    factory DetailModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DetailModel(
        the0: The0.fromJson(json["0"]),
        the1: The0.fromJson(json["1"]),
        records: Records.fromJson(json["records"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "0": the0.toJson(),
        "1": the1.toJson(),
        "records": records.toJson(),
    };
}

class Records {
    int status;
    String message;

    Records({
        this.status,
        this.message,
    });

    factory Records.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Records(
        status: json["status"],
        message: json["message"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": message,
    };
}

class The0 {
    String id;
    String sku;
    int sak;
    String qty;
    String shipstatId;
    String picName;
    String picTelp;
    String orderMultipleId;
    String orderdetId;
    String coordinatorId;

    The0({
        this.id,
        this.sku,
        this.sak,
        this.qty,
        this.shipstatId,
        this.picName,
        this.picTelp,
        this.orderMultipleId,
        this.orderdetId,
        this.coordinatorId,
    });

    factory The0.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => The0(
        id: json["id"],
        sku: json["sku"],
        sak: json["sak"],
        qty: json["qty"],
        shipstatId: json["shipstat_id"],
        picName: json["pic_name"],
        picTelp: json["pic_telp"],
        orderMultipleId: json["order_multiple_id"],
        orderdetId: json["orderdet_id"],
        coordinatorId: json["coordinator_id"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "sku": sku,
        "sak": sak,
        "qty": qty,
        "shipstat_id": shipstatId,
        "pic_name": picName,
        "pic_telp": picTelp,
        "order_multiple_id": orderMultipleId,
        "orderdet_id": orderdetId,
        "coordinator_id": coordinatorId,
    };
}
```

And here is the Error,

[image]

Comment: you need to use FutureBuilder in build method.

Comment: check if the0!=null before  doing toJson

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I'm actually newbie in Flutter, can you show me how to use it..?

Comment: @StellarCreed Is that different from the NULL CHECKING I've used..?

Comment: @edodije try to replace  "0": the0.toJson(), to  "0": (the0!=null) ? the0.toJson() : null,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use FutureBuilder in build method and wait until response.

Remove `setstate` and Modify the code as below.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'Test',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<DetailModel>(
        future: getDetail(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
             print("Here you can get data "+snapshot.data.toString());
          } else {
            print("Waiting mode");
            return Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I've done this but I didn't get the data, I mean it's even not printing, is that mean that the snapshot has no data..?